# Getting information from Annotation processor at runtime

Tags: java, annotations, runtime

I have a working annotation processor that gathers information of the annotated classes. Everything is there during compilation. But I would like to have access to those results during runtime.

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class TestProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private final static List<TestInfo> tests = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Set getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return new LinkedHashSet() {
            {
                add(Annotation.class.getCanonicalName());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            final RoundEnvironment env) {
        System.out.println("Processing!");
        if (!env.processingOver()) {
            Set<? extends Element> rootE = env.getRootElements();
            for (Element e : rootE) {
                if (e.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
                    TestInfo t = new TestInfo(e.asType().toString());
                    for (Element se : e.getEnclosedElements()) {
                        if (se.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) {
                            t.addMethod(se.getSimpleName().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    getTests().add(t);
                }
            }
            getTests().forEach(ti -> {
                System.out.println(ti);
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static TypeElement findEnclosingTypeElement(Element e) {

        while (e != null && !(e instanceof TypeElement)) {
            e = e.getEnclosingElement();
        }

        return TypeElement.class.cast(e);
    }

    /**
     * @return the tests
     */
    public static List<TestInfo> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the results at runtime? TestProcessor.getTests returns an empty list.

Here's the TestInfo class fyi:

```
public class TestInfo {

    private final String name;
    private final List<String> methods = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestInfo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addMethod(String m) {
        getMethods().add(m);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the methods
     */
    public List<String> getMethods() {
        return methods;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(name).append(methods.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Update:** The annotation is marked with retention runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation-processing is in compile time. So you can't get the information in the runtime.

A direct way is to write the information as a resource file in compile time and read it at runtime.

Here is my example:

The annotation:

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface Anno {
}
```

The processor:

```
  @Override
  public boolean processActual(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    if (roundEnv.processingOver()) {
      return false;
    }
    try {
      write(roundEnv);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }

  private void write(RoundEnvironment roundEnv) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Filer filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
    FileObject resource = filer.createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "", "TestInfo");
    OutputStream output = resource.openOutputStream();
    PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(output, false, "UTF-8");
    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Anno.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS)
        .map(e -> e.asType().toString())
        .forEach(writer::println);
    writer.flush();
  }
```

And the user code:

```
@Anno
public class Q48177784 {
  public static final List<Class<?>> CLASSES;
  static {
    try {
      URL resource = Q48177784.class.getClassLoader().getResource("TestInfo");
      CLASSES = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(resource.toURI()))
          .stream()
          .map(s -> {
            try {
              return Class.forName(s);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              throw new Error(e);
            }
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CLASSES);
  }
}
```

After build with processor, run the `main` method:

```
[class xdean.stackoverflow.Q48177784]
```

For your case, the only thing you should do is serialize/deserialize your `TestInfo`

Comment: Excellent! This was exactly a valid option for me. I didn't have control over the annotation so changing it to source was not an option. I was able to use the write to file approach as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `@RetentionPolicy`. I think you want to set it to `RUNTIME`.

Comment: The annotation is set up for RUNTIME. Forgot to add that.

Comment: `RUNTIME` is not necessary for this question. The principle of `RetentionPolicy` is like `AcessLevel(public/private)`, to use the lowest level as you can.